Elasticsearch: Giving higher score to repetitive field than exact field
I have an Elasticsearch database in which all documents have a name field and are queried by this field.
By default, Elasticsearch search gives higher score to document with repetitive name. But, in my case, I am trying to get exact with high score.
For Example when I search for 'pencil' results are like that:

name: "pencil pencil"
name: "pencil"

so 2.score lower than 1.
I have tried query
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "+red ",
                        "default_field": "type"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "+pencil ",
                        "default_field": "name"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}


In the analyzer for the name field use the unique token filter which

Removes duplicate tokens from a stream. For example, you can use the unique filter to change the lazy lazy dog to the lazy dog.

This assumes the field is mapped as text and not as a term. If it's a term field then the term query should be used.

Thanks for answer, but I dont want to remove duplications, I just try to boosting query results for exact name. "lazy dog" score should higher than "lazy lazy dog".

One of solutions is to override a similarity in mapping
I use doc.freq

doc.freq (long, read-only):: The number of occurrences of the
current term in the current document for the current field.

Mapping
PUT /repetitive_similarity
{
    "settings": {
        "similarity": {
            "matched_term_count": {
                "type": "scripted",
                "script": {
                    "source": "doc.freq * 1.5"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "text": {
                "type": "text",
                "similarity": "matched_term_count"
            }
        }
    }
}

Documents
PUT /repetitive_similarity/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"text":"lazy lazy lazy dog"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"text":"lazy lazy dog"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"text":"lazy dog"}

Query
GET /repetitive_similarity/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source,hits.hits._score
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "text": {
                "query": "lazy dog"
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_score" : 6.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "text" : "lazy lazy lazy dog"
                }
            },
            {
                "_score" : 4.5,
                "_source" : {
                    "text" : "lazy lazy dog"
                }
            },
            {
                "_score" : 3.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "text" : "lazy dog"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

You could customize the similarity in mapping. If you want that exact values have higher positions in the hits, you could reverse the sort order or modify the score function
Query with the ascending order of the score
GET /repetitive_similarity/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source,hits.hits._score
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "text": {
                "query": "lazy dog"
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": "asc"
        }
    ]
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_score" : 3.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "text" : "lazy dog"
                }
            },
            {
                "_score" : 4.5,
                "_source" : {
                    "text" : "lazy lazy dog"
                }
            },
            {
                "_score" : 6.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "text" : "lazy lazy lazy dog"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

